Running/Converting Opt model written in Pulp to Pyomo
I have created a quite a complex optimization model in pulp a while back, where I can utilize either Gurobi or CBC to solve the models. But now the requirement is getting created for me to use Ocetract engine to solve the model (as it's much faster) and octeract is not yet supported by Pulp but it does get supported by Pyomo (or through AMPL).
Now, as my model is quite complex, I am not really looking forward to converting my complete code to Pyomo from pulp, and was wondering if there is any other way I can use Pyomo to solve the models? Can I take the LP (or MPS or any other) file from Pulp and give that as an input to Pyomo to solve based using my preferred solver? If yes, how? Any other alternative if this doesn't work?

Octeract is for nonconvex nonlinear problems, while PuLP is only for linear problems. PuLP will, in all likelihood, never support Octeract.
